# Cannot extract BLOB from the database

Tags: php, mysql, web, wamp

I am using wamp server and phpmyadmin and php for implementing my database application. I have stored BLOB files in the database. But I am not able to extract the blob file in the original format and allow the user download it in the original format. Can somebody please help me? The screenshot of the format of the blob when I extract it from the database is attached.

[image]

The code for extracting from the database is also attached. The code extracts everything properly except BLOBS. Please someone help me.

```
foreach($_POST['passport'] as $entry) 
{
    $sql = "SELECT $entry FROM passport WHERE UID = '$j'";
    $a = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $b = mysqli_fetch_array($a);
    $c = $b[0];
    echo "<tr><td>{$entry}</td><td>$c</td></tr>";
}
```

[The screenshot of the image as I have mentioned in my comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdWjj.jpg)

Comment: So the problem isn't that you *can't* extract the `BLOB`, it's that it's not displaying correctly?

Comment: You might want to read up on sql injection and xss attacks. Also fix your variable names while you are at it.

Comment: What is the `BLOB` supposed to be? An image?

Comment: Yes @marcus the problem is that it is not displaying properly. Blob is binary large object. Here I have stored image in the database

Comment: I ask only because you're not attempting to actually display an image (no `<img>` anywhere.

Comment: How do I do that? Just putting the variable inside the image tag will work? But I dont want to display the image. How do I provide it as a link to the user so that he can download it?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach ($_POST['passport'] as $entry) 
{
    $sql = "SELECT $entry FROM passport WHERE UID = '$j'";
    $a = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $b = mysqli_fetch_array($a);
    $c = $b[0];
    echo '<tr><td><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($entry) . '"></td><td>' . $c . '</td></tr>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Marcus. That helped. But not completely. Now I am getting something like this- All the characters are gone, But, I am not able to download that image or open that image. There is a small icon of a broken image on the left and the name of the image on the right. I have a screenshot. But I am unable to attach in the comment. Please help me!

Comment: I have added an the snapshot at the end of the question @Marcus

Comment: Somebody please help me solving this problem.

Comment: How did you store the BLOB in the DB in the first place? What was your code to do that? There are dozens of instances of this exact question (with answers) on SO. If you're in a rush, and have nobody here to help, I'd suggest you do a quick search on the topic. To be honest, I've never used BLOB format in my life. There are more efficient ways of storing/handling images, IMO.

Comment: Thank you for helping me @Marcus.  Can u help me with the other ways of storing the images in the database? Please?